# How do I get my Java App to run from the MacOS desktop menu bar like a status app?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, macos-catalina

I'm coding with JavaFX 8, and I'm wondering if there is any way I can make my app behave like those apps we often see that run as little icons in the System menu bar so that when you click on it, you just get a small pop-down window but of course with you java program running in it.

:-)

Here are some screenshots with an example of what I'm wanting to do.

[image]

[image]

Can this be done with Java?

Thank you,

Michael Sims

Comment: Hey Michael, were you able to find anything? I'm looking to do the same!

Comment: @Saket - I posted an answer of what I did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only support currently is the [SystemTray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html) class of AWT.

I've seen Swing samples based on that class in the past, and there are JavaFX classes for interoperability between Swing and JavaFX.

So you might want to try and combine AWT, Swing and JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a library that solved my problem.

JavaFX still does not have a native way of running an app from the title bar (*nix) or the system tray (Windows), but [FXTrayIcon](https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon) is a library that solved this problem for me as it works well enough for my needs given JavaFX's limitations in this regard.